# Exception when trying to sort DataGrid Column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

***Note: Fixed the SummeryName typo to avoid confusion.***

I'm trying to make a simple DataGrid bound to an ObservableCollection sortable by column. It's a simple setup:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DocuObjects}" CanUserSortColumns="True" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedDocu}" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" SortMemberPath="SummaryName" Width="*" Binding="{Binding SummaryName}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The binding source is a simple collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<DocuObject> DocuObjects
{
    get { return m_Docus; }
    set
    {
        m_Docus= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("DocuObjects");                
    }               
}
```

Every time I click on the column header, I get an exception:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 55 : Cannot sort by 'SummaryName'
>   InvalidOperationException:'System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to
>   compare two elements in the array. ---> System.ArgumentException: At
>   least one object must implement IComparable.

So obviously the next step I'm taking it to implement IComparable in the DocuObject class, as the exception suggests. But that doesn't seem to do anything, regardless of whether I add IComparable or IComparable. The exception still occurs, and my CompareTo() code doesn't get hit when I add a breakpoint.

For test purposes, I've simplified my code down to *this* - but that NotImplementedException is not even getting hit.

```
public class DocuObject: INotifyPropertyChanged, IEquatable<DocuObject>, IComparable<DocuObject>
{
...
    public int CompareTo(DocuObject other)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

What fundamental error am I making? SummaryName itself is a string, where CompareTo should work

Comment: Show structure of DocuObject

Comment: I just did. But there's nothing to see :-/

Comment: Please provide more information on the DocuObject class. What type is SummeryName? Is that a typo of SummaryName?

Comment: Please show the code for DocuObject

Comment: SummaryName is not a string object. (Anymore - it used to be one.) So it sounds like I need to implement IComparable on that custom class. Gonna do that and report back.

Comment: @Drakestar I went ahead and set up the exact same situation in a WPF project in Visual Studio and it worked perfectly with strings, so that is most likely your problem.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't a string (anymore).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSDN documentation explains how you can allow columns to be used for sorting:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canusersortcolumns(v=vs.110).aspx

> You can set this sorting behavior for individual columns by setting the DataGridColumn.CanUserSort property.

Is the property actually called `SummeryName`? I will continue under the assumption that is not a typo. You need to set both `SortMemberPath="SummeryName"` and `CanUserSort="True"` for the specific text column.

Unless your names are evocative of summer you might want to change the property from `SummeryName` to `SummaryName`

Also I am assuming `SummeryName` is a string, but if it is not then it must implement IComparable to be sorted.

Comment: According to the documentation for CanUserSortColumns: "Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the user can sort columns by clicking the column header." So I'm setting that and SortMemberPath to indicate which value to sort by (theoretically). The same thing happens as before when I remove it again: the expection fires and my CompareTo code doesn't get hit.

Comment: Ah I see. Give me a minute to look at how I have implemented this before

Comment: `CanUserSort` and `CanUserSortColumns` seem to default to True, btw. I still get the clicking behavior and exception when I remove the property. Things only stop "working" when I explicitly set it to false.

Comment: Can you please provide more information on the DocuObject and SummeryName?

Answer (score 1):

The type behind the `SummeryName` property needs to implement `IComparable`, not the `DocuObject` type. You set `SortMemberPath="SummeryName"` after all.

Answer (score 1):

> But that doesn't seem to do anything, regardless of whether I add IComparable or IComparable.

Since you use `SortMemberPath="SummeryName"`, it means that `SummeryName` should implement `IComparable` (and not IComparable). If it is a string, check for typos. If it is a custom class, `DataGrid` calls `CompareTo` in it:

```
public class CustomClass : IComparable
{  
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not missing IComparable on the DocuObject...the problem is the missing IComparable on whatever object you are using for SummeryName.  If you use string for SummeryName the sorting will work fine.  This is because string implements IComparable.